# how to use oracle dbms_utility in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle9i

I want to use ORACLE DBMS feature in my C# application to compile all the invalid objects but I received below error. would you please help me how I can run below script in C#:

> "exec dbms_utility.compile_schema('"+schema+"');";

my function :

```
internal void compileAllInvalideObject(string userId, string password, string schema)
        {
            //OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            string connectionString = "provider=MSDAORA;data source="+userId+";user id="+userId+";password="+password;

            OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            OleDbCommand myOleDbCommand = myOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();

            myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "exec dbms_utility.compile_schema('"+schema+"');";

            myOleDbConnection.Open();

            myOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            myOleDbConnection.Close(); 

        }
```

error:

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

I am using oracle 9i.

Answer (score 2):

Actually dbms_utility.compile_schema act same as store procedure so we can not call it in same way which we run a query, we need to write program in such way we call a store procedure.

```
 OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

            //using connection string attributes to connect to Oracle Database
            con.ConnectionString = "User Id="+userId+";Password="+password+";Data Source="+schema;


            OracleCommand ocb = new OracleCommand("dbms_utility.compile_schema", con);
            ocb.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ocb.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@schema", userId));
            con.Open();
            ocb.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion);
            // Close and Dispose OracleConnection object
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried but I dont know why still number of invalid object didnt decreased?!!! Any idea?

Comment: Seriously?  Fifteen months on and you're just picking this up?

Comment: @APC, no not like that, I used it but as you can observe I didnt choose it as accepted answer, becuase my objects are still invalid. everything run succesfully but all objects are invalid. The second reason for that I am looking into it again is because yesterday I just able to use ODP instead of microsoft component. ;) that why I again try same thing and when I google my problem again I reach to my own question without answer :(

Comment: When you say "everything run successfully" what do you mean?  How are you checking whether objects are invalid?  Have you tried recompiling an individual object to see whether it compiles?  What type of objects - views? stored procs?  SQL types?

Comment: @apc: it means that I am not receiving any exception, but there is no effect on the invalid objects. your second question answer is yes if I manually recompile them with benthic they get compiled.